# Cannot Autowire spring cloud stream binding to use in an integration flow bean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm new to spring cloud stream and trying out a few things. I'm using spring boot 3.0.1 and spring cloud 2022.0.0. When I try to autowire the cloud stream bindings in one of my Integration flow beans I get an error saying that it cannot find the message channel bean in the application context.

I'm trying to create a integration flow which will poll a directory and read the records in the file to be published to kafka. I'm using the file adapters in spring integration to poll directories and when it finds a file it passes a message to a message splitter that publishes a list of messages one for each line. These messages from the splitter are passed to a spring cloud outbound adapter to be published to kafka.

Here is the integration dsl

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileUploadFlow (FileRecordSplitter fileRecordSplitter, @Qualifier(value = "author-publisher-out-0")MessageChannel messageChannel) {
    return IntegrationFlow.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(FILE_PATH)).patternFilter("*final.txt").scanEachPoll(true),
            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)))
            .split(fileRecordSplitter)
            .channel(messageChannel)
            .get();
}
```

and here is my property file:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: book-file-upload-utility
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers:
            - @cluster.host@
          autoCreateTopics: false
          producerProperties:
            configuration:
              key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.VoidSerializer
              value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
      function:
        autodetect: false
      output-bindings: author-publisher
      bindings:
        author-publisher-out-0:
          binder: spring-kafka
          destination: file-upload-publisher
          producer:
            useNativeEncoding: true
management:
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: true
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
          - health
          - env
          - beans
          - bindings
server:
  port: 8085
```

This is the stacktrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fileUploadFlow' defined in class path resource [org/spring/project/file/upload/utility/integration/FileUploadIntegrationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'fileUploadFlow' parameter 1: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("author-publisher-out-0")}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:548) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.spring.project.file.upload.utility.FileUploadUtilityApplication.main(FileUploadUtilityApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("author-publisher-out-0")}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1812) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1371) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 19 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I did remove the binding from the integration flow and made the app to run after which I could see the binding "author-publisher-out-0" bean created by hitting the actuator/beans endpoint. But somehow it is not able to inject it in the integration flow dsl. I wanted a reference to the message channel of the binding to use it on the integration flow and found this in the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-producing-consuming-messages. Would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding, and therefore respective `MessageChannel` is created a bit later than an auto-wiring phase.
Please, consider to do a named channel instead of an injection into bean method:

```
.channel("author-publisher-out-0")
```